# List doesn't keep the values on C# Model

Tags: javascript, arrays, dropzone

I must be doing something wrong.

This is my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool LoadFileListToDelete(string FileIdToDeleteFromServer)
{
ArticleViewModel viewModel = new ArticleViewModel();
bool isRemoved = viewModel.LoadFileListToDelete(FileIdToDeleteFromServer);
return isRemoved;
}
```

Model declaration of the List:

```
public List<string> FilesToDelFromServer { get; set; }
```

Model Method that receive Ids:

```
  public bool LoadFileListToDelete(string FileIdToDeleteFromServer)
  {
    FilesToDelFromServer.Add(FileIdToDeleteFromServer);
    return true;
  }
```

I made a constructor on my ModelView where FilesToDelFromServer List is initialized:

```
    public ArticleViewModel()
    {
    this.Article = new Content.Entities.ContentChannel.Article();
    ImageGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    FilesToDelFromServer = new List<string>();
    Flag = false;

    }
```

The process is the next:

foreach file removed on the JavaScript, my method will  be called adding a new Id to the list. (This is done before "Save Button is pressed" on the form.
But it looks like values just disappear from my list.

The question is, when "Save" is pressed All the viewModel is being saved but this values on my list which should be there are not there.

Please help.

Comment: I can't tell you what you are doing wrong because there is no [mcve] and it is not easy for me to see what the call sequence is here based on what you have provided so far. Do keep in mind that the web server is stateless, any state you want to track server side should be provided in each server side call. Example: if the user selects server items and you want to  persist that then *all* the selected items should be submitted to the server on submit.

Comment: Igor, i saw that type of answer a lot of times. Please understand that sometimes someone cant share all the code. On one hand, i cant compromise the company codes, on the other hand the code is really big and complex to lose time rebuilding a "portable" version. However i tryed to share the important lines that i consider usefull for this.

Comment: Yes, on submit should be the easiest way, add another param to save method (a list) and handle it that way. However i would like to do it different. I dont understand why C# cant keept the value. As i see, you sent a string value to Model, your Model Adds that to the list. Then when somebody save the form. The Model is saved, why, WHY the list will keept the 0 value. If i added it in another method. Maybe im not good at C# at this moment but i really hate his functionallity.